# Prove that if $L \subseteq b^*$ isn't regular then $M = a^+L \cup b^*$ isn't regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, theory

There is an exercise in a [book](https://www.amazon.de/Finite-Automata-Mark-V-Lawson/dp/0367394995/ref=sr_1_2?crid=FFKTPZD0DNFW&keywords=finite%20automata&qid=1705773736&sprefix=finite%20automa%2Caps%2C131&sr=8-2) about finite automata that I couldn't solve:

Prove that if $L \subseteq b^*$ isn't regular then $M = a^+L \cup b^*$ isn't regular either, using the fact that REG is closed under inverse morphism (paraphrase).

I think one obvious approach would be to find a Language $L'$ and morhpism $\varphi$, s.t. $L' = \varphi^{-1}(M)$ and $L'$ can be transformed into $L$ using regular operations.
Does someone have a hint on how to solve this exercise?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Edit: Typeset the wrong formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume towards a contradiction that $M = a^+ L \cup b^*$ is regular.
Then $M' = M \cap a^*b^* = a^+ L$ is also  regular (since it is the intersection of regular languages), [and so is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_of_a_formal_language) $a^* \setminus M' = L$, which contradicts the fact that $L$ is not regular.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again for your fast reply (and your patience).
I'm not sure I understand the construction of $M'$ though, wouldn't $M \cap a^*b^* = (a^+L \cap a^*b^*) \cup (b^* \cap a^*b^*) = a^+L \cup b^*$ since $b^* \subseteq a^*b^*$?

Comment: I think using $M' = M \cap a^+b^*$ instead should work.

Comment: Sure. In both cases $M'$ is just $a^+ L$.